# Foreign Key of Type String in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am using Spring boot for developing Hibernate-JPA. My foreign key is of type String. When I check MYSQL database after Junit tests, I notice that the foreign key field in the database is empty

My code is as below:

Child Class:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "nodes")
public class Nodes { 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private int node_id;
    private String name;
    private Date created_at;    

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="type", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Nodetypes nodetypes;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "nodes", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set <Nodeattributes> nodeattributes;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "nodes", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set <Products> products;

    public Set<Products> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(Set<Products> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

    public Set<Nodeattributes> getNodeattributes() {
        return nodeattributes;
    }

    public void setNodeattributes(Set<Nodeattributes> nodeattributes) {
        this.nodeattributes = nodeattributes;
    }

    public Nodetypes getNodetypes() {
        return nodetypes;
    }

    public void setNodetypes(Nodetypes nodetypes) {
        this.nodetypes = nodetypes;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getNode_id() {
        return node_id;
    }

    public void setNode_id(int node_id) {
        this.node_id = node_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getCreated_at() {
        return created_at;
    }

    public void setCreated_at(Date created_at) {
        this.created_at = created_at;
    }
}
```

Parent Class:

```
    @Entity @Table(name = "node_types")
    public class Nodetypes {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String label;
    private String name;
    private Boolean is_group;
    private Date created_at;
    private String type;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "nodetypes", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Nodes> nodes;

    public Set<Nodes> getNodes() {
        return nodes;
    }

    public void setNodes(Set<Nodes> nodes) {
        this.nodes = nodes;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Boolean getIs_group() {
        return is_group;
    }

    public void setIs_group(Boolean is_group) {
        this.is_group = is_group;
    }

    public Date getCreated_at() {
        return created_at;
    }

    public void setCreated_at(Date created_at) {
        this.created_at = created_at;
}
```

My test conditions are generating an empty field for the foreign key in MYSQL Database

```
    @Test
    public void testCreateNodetype() {
        Nodetypes nodetypes = new Nodetypes();
        nodetypes.setId(1);
        nodetypes.setLabel("myLabel");
        nodetypes.setName(44);
        nodetypes.setIs_group(true);
        nodetypes.setCreated_at(new java.util.Date());

        nodetypesRepository.save(nodetypes);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateNodes() {
        Nodes node1 = new Nodes();
        node1.setCreated_at(new java.util.Date());
        node1.setName("nodeName");
        node1.setNode_id(444);
        node1.setNodetypes(nodetypesRepository.findOne(1));

        nodesRepository.save(node1);
    }
```

here is the MYSql schema used
This is the Parent Table:

```
    CREATE TABLE `node_types` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `label` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'display name',
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'unique identification',
  `is_group` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
)
```

This is the Child Table:

````
    CREATE TABLE `nodes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `node_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `type_foreign_to_node_types` (`type`),

  CONSTRAINT `type_foreign_to_node_types` FOREIGN KEY (`type`) REFERENCES `node_types` (`name`)
) ```

Any help would be apreciated
````

Comment: can you please share minimalistic tables schema as well

Comment: Yes I have. Please see my question

Comment: `(name="type", insertable=false, updatable=false)` what do you see here?

Comment: It's used to say that the field "type" is foriegn key

Comment: But why do you wonder that a field is not inserted, if you specify `insertable=false`?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I think you don't understand about the annotation. Please read the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html) again

Comment: @G.Brown: Are you sure that the tests were run in order?

Comment: To be assured, I ran the first test , next the second one. I am getting foreign key as null

Comment: Did nodetypesRepository.findOne(1) return any result?

Comment: @thanhngo I think you need to read the docs actually. `**insertable**
public abstract boolean insertable
(Optional) Whether the column is included in SQL INSERT statements generated by the persistence provider.
Default:
true`

Comment: @G.Brown change `@JoinColumn(name="type", insertable=false, updatable=false)` to `@JoinColumn(name="type")`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer It seems like you don't understand deeply about the property. This states that  the responsibility of creating/updating the related entity isn't in the current entity. Please do some basic example and correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: I did as you suggested. Still I'm getting a null in the daabase

Comment: @G.Brown the schema has problem. Why the foreign key from nodes point to unique key (name) in node types. I think it should point to the primary key (id)

Comment: That's how I got the requirement as. "Foreign key  as a String"

Comment: So this will not work. May be this [article](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-a-manytoone-association-using-a-non-primary-key-column/) helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found one issue with entity modeling for below class

```
CREATE TABLE `node_types` (
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'unique identification'
```

```
@Entity @Table(name = "node_types")
    public class Nodetypes {
    private int name;
```

change resturn type of name from int to String

```
@Entity @Table(name = "node_types")
    public class Nodetypes {
    private String name;
```

Change the test method as well to

```
    @Test
    public void testCreateNodetype() {
      ...
        nodetypes.setName("44");
      ... 
    }
```

This should work fine.

Here are entries in tables:

[image: nodetypes]
[image: nodes]
[image]

Comment: I did as you suggested. Still I'm getting a null in the daabase

Comment: You shouldn't, will share code details which I tried. give me 5mins

Comment: There are some other class as well, please ignore them and consider only required: https://github.com/dineshbhagat/spring-boot-web-jpa/tree/master/src/main/java/com/example/entity

Comment: clone complete project and you can run JUnit which will create entry in both the tables

Comment: Tests are here: https://github.com/dineshbhagat/spring-boot-web-jpa/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/jpa/JPAEntityLevelTests.java

Comment: Let me know if you face any issue

Comment: should I download the whole project?

Comment: yes, give it a try, or you can download only files which you need and add it in your project and run, or just check the diff with your source code and add those changes and try, there are multiple ways

Comment: Okay.I'll try . Give me a couple of minutes

Comment: I tried Everything. Something seems to miss, with your code it gives SQLGrammar eexception (or) leaves the foriegn key as null. I uploaded my project as zip, with schema as well. Please look at it once. Its a direct download. heres the link

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/b290dfea1d010085d0eb19181369437b20190515103242/65923fc11ba38730a809bd1a71378d8520190515103242/7b1a78

Comment: @G.Brown Above changes worked for me with your codebase. check image above

Comment: In hibernate, String can not be set as Foreign key. The code was correct. The foreign key should be a number